NodeJS: How to build a Realtime worker pool that allow adding and removing a worker dynamically
I have a scrapper that must make custom requests to an api. The point is that these requests need to be dynamic, as they can be managed, that is, added or removed. Every time a request is added, the system needs to immediately start scraping.
Obs: The requests run in a loop format, so, when once request is finished, another equal is fired.
I've been researching NodeJS workers and promises, but I haven't found a way to build this pool in realtime yet. Could you give me some guidance on this problem?

You need a job queue. You add to the queue and have workers listen to it. Then you can deploy your app on X instances and the first free will take the next job and so on.
